# TLS communication not happening when service acts as a client in Non-root mode

Tags: c++, linux, ssl, soap, gsoap

I have a system which uses SOAP messages for communication. I am using GSoap-2.8.30 version.
For a root user everything works fine.

But when I try the same for non-root user, error occurs while sending the notification.
I am using function like: soap_faultstring() and soap_faultdetail(), to get a detailed reason of failure.
But junk characters are getting printed.

**Code:**

```
 printf("Fault has occured: %s, details: %s.", *soap_faultstring(&soap), *soap_faultdetail(&soap))
```

**Log:**

> Fault has occured: (null), details: P^Q^^8U^?.

I am not sure what is the issue here as the communication is fine for Non-TLS as well as Root user.

Note: I have checked my certificates and they are valid for TLS communication.

Answer (score 0):

There were some configuration files which were not accessible as non-root user. Once their permissions were updated, the issue was resolved.